# Is there a direct way to query and update App data from within a proxy or do I have to use the management API?

Tags: apigee

I have a need to change Attributes of an App and I understand I can do it with management server API calls.

The two issues with using the management server APIs are:

1. **performance**: it’s making calls to the management server, when it
   might be possible directly in the message processor. Performance
   issues can probably be mitigated with caching.
2. **availability**:  having to use management server APIs means that the system is
   dependent on the management server being available. While if it were
   done directly in the proxy itself, it would reduce the number of
   failure points.

Any recommended alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally all entities are stored in the cassandra ( for the runtime )

Your best choice is using access entity policy for getting any info about an entity. That would  not hit the MS. But just for your information - most of the time you do not even need an access entity policy. When you use a validate apikey or validate access token policy - all the related entity details are made available as flow variable by the MP. So no additional access entity calls should be required.

When you are updating any entity (like developer, application) - I really assume it is management type use case and not a runtime use case.  Hence using management APIs should be fine.

If your use case requires a runtime API call to in-turn update an attribute in the application then possibly that attribute should not be part of the application. Think how you can take it out to a cache, KVM or some other place where you can access it from MP (Just a thought without completely knowing the use cases ).

Answer (score 1):

The design of the system is that all entity editing goes through the Management Server, which in turn is responsible for performing the edits in a performant and scalable way. The Management Server is also responsible for knowing which message processors need to be informed of the changes via zookeeper registration.  This also ensures that if a given Message Processor is unavailable because it, for example, is being upgraded, it will get the updates whenever it becomes available.  The Management Server is the source of truth.

In the case of Developer App Attributes, (or really any App meta-data) the values are cached for 3 minutes (I think), so that the Message Processor may not see the new values for up to 3 minutes.

As far as availability, the Management Server is designed to be highly available, relying on the same underlying architecture as the message processor design.

Comment: Thanks for the background information, but is there a better conduit for making changes besides direct MS API calls?

Comment: No.  There is no better way.  My point was that there is no **Availability** issue.  As far as the **Performance** issue, what problem are you seeing

Comment: This is preemptive, so no issues yet.   There have been previous concerns for queue optimization that doesn't occur with direct MS API calls vs. policies/alternatives.